# Is there a way to get pixel data from Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, pixel, vml, getimagedata

Excanvas.js allows IE to work with the canvas tag, but the [getImageData method is not supported.](http://groups.google.com/group/google-excanvas/browse_thread/thread/7d35fa72dbe1487b)

Is there any way at all to get the value of a specified pixel in IE (img or VML or whatever other ways bitmaps from a server can be displayed in IE)? I'm assuming there's not.

I'm trying to get rid of a server hit to improve responsiveness of an Ajax app, but I might only be able to do it for FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari if there's no way to coax the info out of IE.

Comment: What exactly (or as close as you can say) are you trying to do? There might be another way to look at the problem...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the link below...

> ExCanvas does not support any of the
>   ImageData functions (createImageData,
>   getImageData, putImageData).  Given
>   the way it's implemented it's highly
>   unlikely that we'll be able to add
>   support for it in the VML
>   implementation of ExCanvas.
>
> It should
>   be doable in the Silverlight version
>   but we haven't spent much time on that
>   lately.  ExCanvas supports most of the
>   functionality as specified in the
>   initial apple canvas spec but few of
>   the additions added by the gecko
>   implementation and later speced by
>   html5 working group.
>
> The reason being
>   fairly simple, ExCanvas uses VML to do
>   the actual drawing and many of the
>   additions (such as getImageData)
>   requires pixel level access which
>   isn't provided by VML.  Your best bet
>   for now would be to keep track of all
>   commands used to draw the canvas and
>   use those to generate an image server
>   side.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-excanvas/browse_thread/thread/7d35fa72dbe1487b

Why can't IE just use a real canvas like all the other kids....

Comment: "Why can't IE just use a real canvas like all the other kids...." In it's defence it now does in IE9 and also with hardware acceleration!